# Calling a method from an imported python file

Tags: python, oop, class

I have this directory structure.
In my project root directory I have a main python file say main.py. Also in the this root direcory there is folder called Tests. This test folder will have series of test files (known only at run time) e.g test1.py,test2.py etc...
In my testfiles e.g Test1.py I have this sort of structure:

```
from  TestBase import TestBase          
class Test1(TestBase):              
    def TestFunction(self):    
        # do_some_stuff
```

In my main.py I want to call this TestFunction(). How do I do this ?

```
     # use sys.path.append() to add Tests directory our path           
     x= import(testfilename)        
     result = x.TestFunction() # something like this method from class in testfilename
```

Comment: It's not clear what your code means.  What is the relevance of `class Test1`?  Is `TestFunction()` a method on this class?  It has a `self` parameter after all, but is not indented.  But then again, you call `x.TestFunction()` in the second code snippet, as if `TestFunction()` was a module-level function.  Any clarifications would be nice.

Comment: @Sven I have improved formatting and added info Each test file has a class in it named after the name of the file.For instance test1.py has a class named Test1, test2.py has Test2 etc.. TestFunction is a method in class Test1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Python 2.7, the functionality you need is included in the built-in `unittest` module.  For earlier versions of Python this module has been backported under the name [`unittest2`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/0.5.1).

If for some reason you want to roll your own test discovery, here is a basic approach:

```
import glob
import sys
import TestBase
sys.path.append("tests")
for path in glob.iglob("tests/*.py"):
    module = __import__(os.path.basename(path)[:-3])
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, TestBase.TestBase):
            test = obj()
            test.TestFunction()
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does:                                      if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, TestBase.TestBase):
            test = obj()

Comment: This tests if `obj` is a subclass of `TestBase`, and if it is, creates an instance of that class.

Comment: Just to confirm if I understand right isinstance(obj,type) checks if obj is of type 'class'. In our example it would check if Test1 is of type class and whether derives from TestBase

Comment: @johnnyalpaca: Your understanding is correct.  The first part of the check (`isinstance(obj, type)`) is only to prevent the second part (`issubclass(obj, TestBase.TestBase)`) from throwing an exception, which is what would happen if `obj` is not a type at all.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure how u want to add test files at run time.. i would try this,

> `try:
>       import Test.test1 as t1
>       test= True;
>    except ImportError:
>       test = False ;`

You can use system call to find no of test file available at run time. Then try to import them using for loop as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do something like this
if testfilename is in /test/ dir

```
m = __import__('test.testfilename')
t = m.Test1()
x = t.TestFunction()
```

let me know if it works